# How do we know that Quasars actually produce collimated jets?

Tags: astrophysics, relativistic-jets, quasars

How did astrophysicists know this? Of course it's very difficult to directly see the jets from Quasars, so I'm wondering how did they come to the conclusion that Quasars produce collimated jets or beams?

Comment: How "collimated" do you mean? Are you simply interested in how we know about the presence of [astrophysical jets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrophysical_jet) in general, or are you particularly concerned with degree of collimation?

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance I'm just concerned about how they concluded that Quasars produce jets, regardless of how collimated they are.

Comment: I added in two sources, one calling them jets, and the other more restrained in it's attribution to the phenomenon  being a jet, but you would need to search through the paper, which  should easy to find based on the extract below. But if it's not a jet, or an artifact  (which seems unlikely) then what is it? Any gravitational source surely could not pull a  linear stream of matter in this fashion, if had any angular velocity with respect to the quasar. Anyway, thanks for asking the question, I learnt a lot from it.

Answer (score 3):

Because of images such as this one.

[image]

Source: [Radio Image of Quasar](http://arstechnica.com/science/2014/11/black-hole-jets-how-do-they-work-magnets/)

> A radio image of a quasar, taken by the Very Large Array. The white dot in the middle is the core, while the protrusions pointed top-left and bottom-right are jets, traveling at relativistic speeds, culminating in lobes.
>
> It’s not known for sure what causes the jets. It’s thought that the black hole’s spin and mass interact with the magnetic field near the black hole to accelerate the particles. While some evidence supports this model, it's been difficult to test, mainly because scientists lacked a full knowledge of how bright the accretion disks is. But a new study of a sample of blazars (quasars with jets that point toward Earth) shows a clear correlation between the jets' power and the accretion disk’s brightness. This suggests that the magnetic field is a factor in producing the jets.
>
> The researchers examined 217 blazars using data obtained by the Fermi observatory, looking for some relationship between the jets’ power and the accretion disk. Blazars are useful because with a blazar, we get direct light from both the accretion disk and the jet, since the latter is pointed toward us. And we can tell which is which, because light from the jet is mostly in the form of gamma rays, while the accretion disk produces a broader emission spectrum.
>
> It turns out that when the luminosity of the jets are graphed against the luminosity of the disk, there’s a clear, straight-line relationship, with the jet having more power than the disk’s luminosity.

[image]

From this paper **Jet Formation and Collimation in AGN and µ-Quasars**,   it would appear to depend somewhat on the velocity of the outflow.

I apologise I cannot provide a link to the paper, as my tablet cannot copy that , but from my limited reading, (and knowledge ), the collimation of the jet seem to depend it's velocity , which to me, makes intuitive sense.

> Abstract. We briefly review our current understanding for the formation, acceleration and collimation of winds to jets associated with compact astrophysical objects such as AGN and µQuasars. All such outows may be considered to a rst approximation as ideal MHD plasmas escaping from a rotating and magnetized accretion disk with a magnetosphere around a central black hole. A crucial ingredient for a correct modelling of the steady state problem is to place the appropriate boundary conditions, by taking into account how information can propagate through the outow and ensuring, e.g., that shocks produced via the interaction of the ow with the external medium do not a ect the overall structure. As an example underlining the role of setting the correct boundary conditions, we make the analogy of the critical surfaces in the steady and axisymmetric MHD problem with the event horizon and ergosphere of a rotating black hole in relativity. We discuss the acceleration of the outow, by gas, radiation, or wave pressure gradients and also by magnetic mechanisms, showing the important role played by the disk corona in the vicinity of the black hole. Pressure and magnetic connement both may also play a role in conning the outow, although magnetic hoop stress connement is likely to be a rather dominant process in tightly collimated outows.

Comments included  here in case of deletion  and due to their relevance.

From Kyle Kanos

> It is my understanding that a collimated jet is one that lies asking the axis of rotation of the object ejecting it. The image in question & its description absolutely does not show this is the case.

From WetSavannaAnimal aka Rod Vance.

> That is a good point - that we don't know whether the jet and rotation axis co-incide. But then the question arises: how do we know the rotation axis? We would need to resolve the accretion disk directly to at least see its orientation and / or resolve Doppler effects / relativistic beaming asymmetries in brightness. In any case, as in most of physics, this is supporting evidence for a jet, pending possible falsification by any demonstration that the rotation axis and jet do not co-incide.

I feel these two comments above do sum up the issue pretty well.

I would defer to Kyle's greater understanding of the subject regarding collinimation, but to a newbie is seems reasonable if you extend the concept from neutron stars to quasars. But as we, AFAIK,  have much less knowledge of quasars, it may not be a correct extrapolation to make.

I would stress I am painfully aware that I am open to correction on all aspects of this.

Comment: How does that image show that it is collimated?

Comment: @KyleKanos  Fair point, after I posted it, I looked up the definition of collimated and got _make (rays of light or particles) accurately parallel._   which is how it looks to me, from the length and constant width over such a long distance, I can't immediately see that it fails to fulfill that criteria,  But if   that is not the strictly accurate **physics** definition, (and I do take your point there), I will either provide supporting evidence shortly or delete it, in  the absence of such evidence. Thanks for clarification on what I need to confirm.

Comment: I've never seen this picture, I did not think it was possible given how far Quasars are. However I am pretty sure physicists concluded that they are jets using several different methods rather than just pictures. I am not sure what methods they used, so that's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: I think there can be some latitude in the definition  of "collimated" - after all, no light source is truly collimated unless the beam is of infinite width: there is always a nonzero divergence angle. I'm guessing that the OP is simply interested in astrophysical jets, rather than a super precise degree of collimation. So I think this is a valid answer: we can see them in many cases.

Comment: @user43783 If you are looking for non-imaging methods, then you should say so in your question - as it stands, this answer is a valid one to your question.

Comment: I did not think it was possible either, but Kyle's point is valid, how do I know it's collimated?. I am searching for supporting evidence, while using the Wikipedia definition of collimated as _Collimated light is light whose rays are parallel, and therefore will spread minimally as it propagates._  But it takes little imagination to  guess you know more than I do re: this. All I can say is that, to me, it must fulfil the above criterion, otherwise it would diverge, especially considering the length. Please bear with me as I keep on searching. If I am incorrect, it will be deleted

Comment: @WetSavanna: it is my understanding that a *collimated jet* is one that lies asking the axis of rotation of the object ejecting it. The image in question & its description absolutely does not show this is the case.

Comment: @KyleKanos That is a good point - that we don't know whether the jet and rotation axis co-incide. But then the question arises: how do we know the rotation axis? We would need to resolve the accretion disk directly to at least see its orientation and / or resolve Doppler effects / relativistic beaming asymmetries in brightness. In any case, as in most of physics, this is supporting *evidence* for a jet, pending possible falsification by any demonstration that the rotation axis and jet do not co-incide.

Comment: @KyleKanos thanks for your comments. I think I see your point about collimation now, I wonder why it does not have a jet/beam......symmetrical on the "far side" to what my source calls a jet.

Comment: The fact that you don't see the beam on the far side is probably owing to relativistic beaming - *i.e.* the beam with velocity component towards us is brightened. This is evidence that the jet seen is highly relativistic.

Comment: Another point to note is that it is hard to imagine a mechanism whereby *any* spinning object could shoot matter out in any direction other than along its rotation axis. Otherwise, the launch point would need to be constantly rotating relative to the body. The only exception to this is when stuff is thrown off tangentially to the rotation, most probably at the equator. But then one needs a mechanism whereby this happens only on one tangent, and not all (so you'd get stuff squirting in all directions).

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance  thank you very much for taking the time to answer and explain that.  I absolutely should have read up more on quasars themselves before answering. Am I kicking myself because it's obvious now, yes....... Another lesson learnt.

Comment: Don't beat yourself up - it's good to have these conversations. Grand to hear from you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a question with a definitive answer. However, even before imaging of collimated jets from (some) quasars became possible there were clear indications of the jet phenomena from a type of quasar referred to as [blazars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blazar) or sometimes [BL Lac objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BL_Lac_object). These quasars were characterised by a *very* high inferred intrinsic luminosity (compared with most quasars) and a broad, rapidly varying and highly polarised, non-thermal continuum spectrum with few or weak discrete spectral features.

The interpretation of these objects was (and still is) that they are a population of otherwise "normal" quasars that have an orientation such that their relativistic jets are pointing along our line of sight. These produce highly beamed (collimated) radiation (predominantly synchrotron) and the high luminosities are explained by high Lorentz factors and Doppler boosting. This  explanation demands that the quasars produce highly collimated jets of particles.